# How to achieve Dynamic Routing in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

new to react. I am creating a react app and want to use react routing to create dynamic routes which will display information when you click a card. For example if I click on the card it will redirect me to a page of information about the certain recipe.

I have a list of recipes like this.

App.js

```
<Grid container>
    {recipeList.map((recipe) => (
      <Grid item key={recipe.recipe.label} xs={12} md={6} lg={4}>
        <Box m={2}>
              <CardRecipe
                key={recipe.recipe.calories}
                title={recipe.recipe.label}
                calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
                image={recipe.recipe.image}
              />
        </Box>
      </Grid>
    ))}
```

I have tried doing something like this but I have no idea what I am doing.

```
   <Router>
          <div>
            <Route path="/recipe" component={RecipeDetails} />
          </div>
   </Router>
```

Here is my full code:
App Js:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Weekly Menu</h1>
      <Grid container>
        {recipeList.map((recipe) => (
          <Grid item key={recipe.recipe.label} xs={12} md={6} lg={4}>
            <Box m={2}>
              <CardRecipe
                key={recipe.recipe.calories}
                title={recipe.recipe.label}
                calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
                image={recipe.recipe.image}
              />
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        ))}

        {/* <Router>
          <div>
            <Route path="/recipe" component={RecipeDetails} />
          </div>
        </Router> */}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
```

CardRecipe which displays details on card:

CardRecipe.js

```
return (
    <div className="cardRecipeWrapper">
      <Card>
        <CardActionArea>
          <CardContent>
            <CardMedia className="imS" image={image} title={title} />
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
              <img src={image} />
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h5"> Title: {title} </Typography>
            <Typography>
              <strong>Description:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
              consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed odio tortor, accumsan vel
              ullamcorper in, finibus sit amet tortor. Aenean ullamcorper justo
              erat, id venenatis eros porta eu. Aliquam nec nibh nisi. Nunc a
              justo molestie, euismod ante vel, cursus mauris. Nulla rhoncus
              ante tellus, eleifend laoreet magna ultricies ut. Nulla eu dui
              fermentum
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
```

I have the card details displaying information I just need to redirected it to a new page and show more details of the card. Much help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's what [route params](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params) are for. Link to `/recipe/:id` and use the id param to figure out which recipe to display.

Answer (score 0):

The route path should contain 1 `id` value. This value will be unique to each recipes and can be used to fetch details about that.

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Route path="/recipe/:id" component={RecipeDetails} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

Then you can call this route like this -

```
{recipeList.map((recipe) => (
  <Grid item key={recipe.recipe.label} xs={12} md={6} lg={4}>
    <Box m={2}>
      <Link to={`recipe/${recipe.recipe.id}`}
        <CardRecipe
           key={recipe.recipe.calories}
           title={recipe.recipe.label}
           calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
           image={recipe.recipe.image}
        />
     </Link>
    </Box>
  </Grid>
))}
```